# How to use hooks in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use hooks in CodeIgniter like

```
class SessionData{
    var $CI;

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function initializeData() {
          // This function will run after the constructor for the controller is ran
          // Set any initial values here
          if(!$this->session->userdata('username')){    //this is line 13
             redirect('login');
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/84-playing-with-hooks-in-codeigniter

Comment: i want to user a hook for check the login credential. so that no need to check in all controller

Comment: what `hook point` are you using? please add more details